# react onClick event is not firing in Samsung Native Browser

Tags: reactjs, samsung-mobile

```
class Clicked extends React.Component{
  mark(){
   console.log('clicked');
  }
  render()
  {
    return (<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick={this.mark.bind(this)}>click</a>)
  }
}
```

Above click is not firing in Samsung native browser/

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/2055#issuecomment-52394598 ?

Comment: I have tried but it's not working after adding "cursor:pointer " in style

Answer (score 0):

You should try React's synthetic touch events, specifically, `onTouchStart`.
However, using `onTouchStart` will invoke `onClick`, so you will either need a property that indicates that the event has fired (so onClick would get ignored), or, you can use different events altogether. such as:

```
render() {
    return (
        <a href="javascript:;" 
            onMouseUp={this.mark.bind(this)}
            onTouchEnd={this.mark.bind(this)}>
            click
        </a>
    )
 }
```